# Syntax highlighting conflict in Vim (when using keyword)

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am quite new to Vim and have the following problem:

In my `.gvimrc` I defined

```
syn keyword Todo PMID
```

to highlight every `PMID` in the files I edit. This works quite well as long as no general syntax highlighting is applied to the file (via `setf` or `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile …`)

My question: How do I maintain a list of individual keywords which are highlighted no matter what file I edit and which syntax highlight I use for that file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case matches come handy:

```
let s:kwreg='\v<%(PMID|OTHER|OTHER2)>'
let s:kwsyn='Todo'
augroup MyKeywords
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinEnter * if !exists('w:my_keyword_mnr') | 
                     \    let w:my_keyword_mnr=matchadd(s:kwsyn, s:kwreg) |
                     \ endif
augroup END
let s:curtab=tabpagenr()
for s:tab in range(1, tabpagenr('$'))
    execute 'tabnext' s:tab
    let s:curwin=winnr()
    for s:win in range(1, winnr('$'))
        execute s:win.'wincmd w'
        let w:my_keyword_mnr=matchadd(s:kwsyn, s:kwreg)
    endfor
    execute s:curwin.'wincmd w'
endfor
execute 'tabnext' s:curtab
unlet s:curtab s:curwin s:tab s:win
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. When I type _PMID_ in a new buffer, it is highlighted. But when I execute _setf …_ this highlighting goes away as well. Best regards and thanks again.

Comment: Does it work if you use `autocmd WinEnter,Syntax * ...` instead?

Comment: @lejonet8 Unable to reproduce: `setf mail`, `set ft=vim`, `filetype detect` (reset filetype to `xdefaults` in this case), `edit` were all unable to clear the highlighting. `setf {what}` did you execute?

Comment: @ZyX I tried it again and it works now. Thank you. I haven’t found a way to clear the highlighting ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Zyx. I've changed my own .vimrc to use this style instead of what I had before. I tweaked it to use `VimEnter,Syntax` instead of `WinEnter`, which works with the initial empty buffer too.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge `Syntax` is the wrong event for this kind of thing. `matchadd()` is local to window only, it is immune to the syntax or even buffer changes. What I should’ve added above (will do now) is iterating over all windows at vim startup. `VimEnter` is also wrong event for this: it is possible to have more then one window at startup. Hence `WinEnter` + loop.

Comment: ZyX, this is a superb solution to my problem. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that highlighted everywhere (as a kind of "overlay"), use `matchadd()`, as shown by ZyX's answer.

If this is a syntax extension for one / a couple of filetypes (e.g. only Java and Python files), put your `:syntax` definition into `~/.vim/after/syntax/<filetype>.vim`. You have to study the original syntax a bit, and possibly add `containedin=<groupNames>` clauses, so that your items properly integrate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
syntax match pmidTODO /TODO\|PMID/
hi link pmidTODO Todo
hi Todo guibg=yellow guifg=black
```

<s>This should work even when `Todo` is redefined by Vim syntax files.</s>

**Edit:** As ZyX pointed out, this does not survive syntax changes.

Comment: Your syntax is not contained, so it won’t apply if text matched another syntax group which started earlier (later defined syntax groups have priority, but not if match started earlier). Your syntax as well will match `pmidTODO`: you do not require `TODO` to be the whole word. Your variant will also go away when syntax is changed. It also won’t apply to new buffers.

Comment: Matthew, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it does not work for me and I will stick with ZyX’s solution. Thank you again for your help.